# How to find and remove a LaunchAgent which has no .plist

Tags: macos, launchd, launchctl, launch-agent

My macOS (v11.2.1) has a number of undesirable LaunchAgents loading with the system, which bloat it. Some of them I was able to successfully remove (just by finding their .plist.) However, for some others I can't simply identify how they're loading during boot, because they have no identifiable .plist.

This post will specifically target VoxAgent (launched by the Vox music player, [www.vox.rocks](http://www.vox.rocks)), but this annoyance also happens with other apps too (CleanMyMac X, Hazel...)

I'm able to terminate the service using `launchctl remove com.coppertino.VOXAgent`, but every time the system boots the service is launched again (even if I don't launch Vox player). What I really want is get rid of such LaunchAgent once and for all, and that's why I need your kind help.

After a fresh reboot, these are the steps I took so far:

**(1)**

I ran `launchctl list` on Terminal, which output was:

```
PID Status  Label
855 0   com.coppertino.VOXAgent
```

**(2)**

I checked the following folders for the presence of any .plist:

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents
/Library/LaunchAgents
/Library/LaunchDaemons
/System/Library/LaunchAgents
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons
```

No .plist related to com.coppertino.VOXAgent was found there.

**(3)**

On Terminal I ran `launchctl blame gui/$(id-u)/com.coppertino.VOXAgent`, which returned:
`semaphore`

**(4)**

On Terminal I ran `launchctl dumpstate | grep -A4 " = {" | grep -B 3 -A 3 -E "active count = [1-9]"`   which returned (showing only the contents related to VoxAgent):

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.om.coppertino.VOXAgent.640 = {
    type = process
    handle = 640
    active count = 33
    on-demand count = 1
--
    security context = {
--
```

and

```
com.coppertino.VOXAgent = {
    active count = 4
    copy count = 0
    one shot = 0
    path = (submitted by otherbsd.426)
--
--
        runatload = 0
--
```

**(5)**

When trying to uninstall Vox using AppCleaner, here's a snapshot of the list of the files associated with this software:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxPeT.png

---

So, what I find surprising is that VoxAgent, as well as some other pesky unidentifiable LaunchAgents (CleanMyMacX, Hazel...), doesn't show the real path to the .plist, but only `path = (submitted by otherbsd.426)`. And this is why I'm having such a hard time to prevent this VoxAgent to load with macOS.

**Other infos that might be helpful (output from Terminal):**

```
id
uid=501(a) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),703(com.apple.sharepoint.group.3),702(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),250(_analyticsusers),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh),400(com.apple.access_remote_ae),704(com.apple.sharepoint.group.4),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1)
```

```
launchctl version                                                                                                           
Darwin Bootstrapper Version 7.0.0: Mon Dec 21 20:06:28 PST 2020; root:libxpc_executables-2038.80.3~7/launchd/RELEASE_X86_64
```

In addition to the steps above, I have already checked the 'Users & Groups > Login Items' as well as 'Extensions' in the System Preferences. Nothing there either which might invoke VoxAgent.

I'm sure there are lots of other people out there having the same trouble. I reviewed many posts here in StackOverflow, but could not find a solution yet.

Thank you in advance for any tips!

Comment: Somewhat ironically, CleanMyMac can be used to achieve this ;)

Comment: Indeed, CleanMyMac can enable or disable some LaunchAgents, but only those with an existing .plist in the expected folders. The other services I mentioned (e.g., Vox, CleanMyMac itself, etc.), which don't have a .plist are not even listed under "LaunchAgents" or "LoginItems" in CMM's 'Optimization' tab.

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem in another app. These are what I found:

[Secret way to launch Agent in Mac? - Apple Community](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8394251)

[Adding Login Items - Apple Developer Archive](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html)

According to the above, there are two ways to add a login item: using the **Service Management framework**, and using a **shared file list**. The login items added using Service Management framework **can only** be deleted by the application itself.

I also want to know if there is a way to disable them because they are so annoying. If there is a way, please also let me know.

At the moment, I am using another startup script to kill the startup items. This can solve the problem, but I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, @ReekyStive. It's really troublesome if some apps stay in the control of their own installed launch agents! I believe a "workaround" would be boycotting those apps and stop using them...